# Output coldfusion xml as raw text

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Any time I try to output coldfusion xml, it removes the tags. How can I print it to screen in its raw format?

Comment: Inside a textarea or between `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Upon actually trying it, `<pre>` tags are ineffective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `<myXmlRoot>` is showing as `myXmlRoot`?

It's not removing the tags, you're trying to display XML as a string and the browser thinks that everything within `<` and `>` is an HTML tag. if you did a `view-source`, you'll see the original XML.

If you're on CF 10+, you can run the XML string through the function `encodeForHTML()`, which will convert what it sees as HTML entities to their relative ASCII values. Previous to CF 10, try `htmlEditFormat()`.

`<cfoutput>#encodeForHTML(myXML)#</cfoutput>` will show the full content of your XML.